django model query two different tables only first table work
Am trying to query two different tables and display there data on a form but only the first table work. pls i need help to display the second table on same form.
acconty = Porjectasset.objects.filter(accountno=acct).values()
stmtacct = Tbltrn.objects.filter(accountno=acct).values()
context={
       'acconty':acconty,

       'stmtacct':stmtacct
                    
     }

IN THE TEMPLATE
{% for xbc in acconty %}
<div.
Project Account No.
{% endfor %}
{% for xc in stmtacct %}
 <div class="form-group">
             
              <b> <b>  Loan Account No : <h3><p style="color:green"><a href="loandash/{{xc.id}}" class="text-primary">{{xc.id}} </a></br></b></p> </b> </b> </h3>
             
              </div>

{% endfor %}

To display data from the second table (Tbltrn) on the same form alongside data from the first table (Porjectasset), you need to ensure that both sets of data are passed to the template correctly. Make sure the variable names used in the template match the ones in the context dictionary. Here's how you can adjust your code.
acconty = Porjectasset.objects.filter(accountno=acct).values()
stmtacct = Tbltrn.objects.filter(accountno=acct).values()

context = {
    'acconty': acconty,
    'stmtacct': stmtacct
}

Make sure to verify that stmtacct contains the expected data. If it does, then ensure that your template correctly accesses and displays the data from stmtacct alongside the data from acconty.

in the template

I have verify stil stmtacct not working
